# In Swift, is there a keyword like self but for the class?

Tags: swift, static, singleton, subclass

```
class mySuperClass{
    static var sharedInstance = mySuperClass()
    var test = "hello"
}
```

In this little snippet, I am setting a static var to mySuperClass() to create a simple singleton.

Is there a way to do this without using the class name mySuperClass?

I ask, because I want to subclass something like this and have the subclass create a sharedInstance of itself and NOT of the super class which is what it does.

Full code here (playground-able):

```
import Cocoa

class mySuperClass{
    static var sharedInstance = mySuperClass()
    var test = "hello"
}

class mySubClass:mySuperClass{
    override init() {
        super.init()
        test = "hello from subclass"
    }
}


print(mySuperClass.sharedInstance.test)

print(mySubClass.sharedInstance.test) //prints test from mySuperClass not subClass
```

Comment: Best you can do is change `static` to `class` and override `sharedInstance`. `mySuperClass` has no idea what subclasses you might derive from it at the point that variable is created.

Comment: Hint: In c++ there is not something like `self` which can refere to the current class, so we use typedef inside class to define self as that class. This type have scope only in that class, so inherited class can have it's new `self` declared differently. Maybe you can use `typealias` in Swift in the same manner.

Answer (score 2):

In other words you want to **subclass a Singleton**.

Let me know if this does solve your problem.

```
class MySuperClass {
    private static let superClassInstance = MySuperClass()
    class var sharedInstance: MySuperClass { return superClassInstance }
    private init() { }

    var test = "hello"
}

class MySubClass: MySuperClass {
    private static let subClassInstance = MySubClass()
    override class var sharedInstance: MySubClass { return subClassInstance }

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        test = "hello from subclass"
    }
}


print(MySuperClass.sharedInstance.test) // "hello"
print(MySubClass.sharedInstance.test) // "hello from subclass"
```